# Boxfuse : Redirect Base URL

Tags: url, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

I have deployed my **Spring Boot** app at **Boxfuse** with base URL as https://example.com . Now, I want to **redirect** the users from this URL to http://example1.com .  This returns **302** status code and application is not getting deployed . I try to set the response code manually , but that does not work . Can Anybody suggest me a workaround for this ? Thanks .

Comment: 302 tells that, the requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your apps has two ports `http` and `https` you can force the healthcheck to happen on the `http` port by setting `healthcheck.port` to `http`. See https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/commandline/run#healthcheck.port

This will avoid the redirect and the check should then succeed.